# LPCWSTR Find & Replace with escape characters

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out how to find and replace a string (that contains escape characters "\"). I can't seem to get this working, I am always short the number of escape characters.

I've tried changing my strings to raw-literal strings, but that did not work for me.

```cpp
LPCWSTR ext1 = _wcslwr(ObjectAttributes->ObjectName->Buffer);

LPCWSTR ext2 = L"c:\\users\\vm1\\documents"; 

LPCWSTR ext3 = L"c:\\users\\vm1\\desktop";

wstring ext4 = Replace(ext1, ext2, ext3);
```

The variable "_wcslwr(ObjectAttributes->ObjectName->Buffer)" is equal to L"\??\c:\users\vm1\documents\temp22.txt".

I keep getting result string of the Replace function below to equal "\??\c:\users\vm1\desktopp22.txt". The result should be "\??\c:\users\vm1\desktop\temp22.txt". Why did it strip out the "\tem" portion? I think it is due to the "\" actually being counted as one character instead of (2) characters.

The called function is below;

```cpp
wstring Replace(const wstring& orig, const wstring& fnd, const wstring& repl)
{
    wstring ret = orig;
    size_t pos = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        pos = ret.find(fnd, pos);
        if (pos == wstring::npos)  // no more instances found
            break;
        ret.replace(pos, pos + fnd.size(), repl);  // replace old string with new string
        pos += repl.size();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I expect the output of the "Replace" function above to be;

```cpp
"\\??\\c:\\users\\vm1\\desktop\\temp22.txt"
```

How do you do this type of find and replace?

Comment: You didn't say how you are calling `Replace()`.

Comment: Variables of type LPCWSTR do not contain escape characters.  Only string literals in a .cpp file do.  This kind of confusion tends to be caused by the debugger showing the variable content in the same format you'd use in C++ source.  Click the spyglass icon to activate the text visualizer popup, shows you what it really looks like.

Comment: Sorry, I added the call to the "Replace" function. Even with the looking glass, there are characters in the LPCWSTR that my "fnd.size()" is not recognizing. That is my question, should I be using something other than ".size()". I was thinking to convert the literal string to raw-literal. I tried this but it threw errors on both ext1, ext2 and ext3 variables. What do I need to do to find the correct length of these strings (account for all the characters between the quotes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't about escape characters, which are not actually part of the string but only present in your source code. The problem is your arguments to [`std::wstring::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace).

Your bounds are as if you were using the `const_iterator, const_iterator` overload, but actually you're using the `start, length` overload. That's not `start, end`!

So:

```
ret.replace(pos, fnd.size(), repl);
```

i.e. remove `pos +`.

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/affb5ea67b7d4faa))

You've been replacing `pos` (4) more characters than you intended.

And, yes, the string library is full of little trip-up points like this, sadly.

Comment: As a side note, please present your [mcve] in a form more similar to that shown in my demo, so we don't have to arse about with it to get it to compile and demonstrate the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Lightness, that did the trick! Many thanks, marked as the correct answer!

Comment: It actually took me a good five minutes of playing around (and some head-scratching) to spot this so I'm not surprised it caught you out! Silly overloads...